# when should I use the session-per-request pattern

Tags: asp.net, database, design-patterns, orm

I see this pattern everywhere, but Linq to SQL does not implement it. If Session/Unit-of-Work objects are lightweight (can be created and destroyed without performance penalty), and connection pooling keeps database connections alive, why and when do I need the session-per-request pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the idea of session-per-request is more about when you open and close the session, not about getting performance improvements.

The idea is that

1. Opening a session will start a transaction before your code is ever called
2. Your business logic *and* your framework has full access to the database until the *last* possible moment
3. Your transaction is committed for you, instead of having to do it each time yourself

The idea of #2 is important so that you can mix web frameworks and lazy loading of data; if a getter method is called while rendering your data after your code has been executed, and you closed the session, you couldn't lazily load that getter's result.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a good question that almost all tutorials seem to avoid.

If you don't use lazy loading, you don't need it.